Uniswap v3 IQuoter / IQuoterV2 return nothing
I'm trying to get Uniswap v3 IQuoter.quoteExactInputSingle() or IQuoterV2.quoteExactInputSingle()in Arbitrum / Base networks in my solidity contract. In both cases Remix show me that decoded output is just '-'.
What can be wrong with it? All addresses are correct and token pools/pairs existed.
    function verifyV3PriceV2(uint amountIn, address tokenIn, address tokenOut) external returns (uint) {
        IQuoterV2.QuoteExactInputSingleParams memory params = IQuoterV2.QuoteExactInputSingleParams({
            tokenIn: tokenIn,
            tokenOut: tokenOut,
            fee: 3000,
            amountIn: amountIn,
            sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
        });
        uint amountOut;
        (amountOut,,,) = IQuoterV2(0x61fFE014bA17989E743c5F6cB21bF9697530B21e).quoteExactInputSingle(params);
        // uint amountOut = IQuoter(0xb27308f9F90D607463bb33eA1BeBb41C27CE5AB6).quoteExactInputSingle(WETH, tokenAddress, 10000, amountIn, 0);
        return amountOut;
    }

remix decoded output
I've tried different networks and tokens. On remix Ethereum fork, this code worked.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

The documentation seems buggy
You have to invert "fee" and "amountIn"
amount first, fee after
